# I would like t o adjust my negative rule to accept any symbol and not just p and store that symbol in a variable

Tags: clips

Hi i have created a clips program and in my defrule negative i am simulating a propositional law and would like the program to accept any symbol and not just a P symbol. I want the defrule to fire no matter the symbol that is there.

I have tried putting ?symbol instead of the P but that has not solved my problem just yet.

```
(deftemplate andprop (slot symbol1)(slot symbol2))
(deftemplate orprop (slot symbol1)(slot symbol2))
(deftemplate implies (multislot premise)(multislot implication))
(deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))

(defrule read-from-user
=>
(printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please " crlf)
(bind ?response (readline))
(assert (sentence(sent ?response))))

(defrule negative
(sentence(sent "~(~P)"))
=>
(printout t "HI " crlf))
```

So i want the defrule negative to fire no matter the symbol that is in symbol so nt only if the symbol is a P

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the explode$ function to split the sentence into separate tokens.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate andprop 
   (slot symbol1)
   (slot symbol2))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate orprop 
   (slot symbol1)
   (slot symbol2))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate implies 
   (multislot premise)
   (multislot implication))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate sentence 
   (multislot sent))
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-from-user
   =>
   (printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please " crlf)
   (bind ?response (readline))
   (assert (sentence (sent (explode$ ?response)))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule negative
   (sentence (sent "~" "(" "~" ?symbol ")"))
   =>
   (printout t "HI " ?symbol crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please 
~(~P)
HI P
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies please 
~(~XYZ)
HI XYZ
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (sentence (sent "~" "(" "~" XYZ ")"))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```